# Deploy and run Spring MVC App on local Tomcat Server

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, model-view-controller

I deploy my war file in Tomcat server and Catalina sends me these errors:

[my project archieve](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Nd4kTnqJFDKOlvPMNB71STqzDzS7ACA6/view?usp=sharing)

I use InteliJ IDE and Tomcat (9 ver).

I tried to change the version of tomcat, unsuccessfully:

```
    06-Jun-2019 23:24:10.352 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
            org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hospital]]
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:744)
                    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:980)
                    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1851)
                    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to register servlet with name 'dispatcher'.Check if there is another servlet registered under the same name.
                    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:193)
                    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.registerDispatcherServlet(AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.java:91)
                    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.onStartup(AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.java:64)
                    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5225)
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
                    ... 10 more
    06-Jun-2019 23:24:10.360 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [C:\tomcat81\webapps\hospital.war]
            java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/hospital]]
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:758)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:744)
                    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:980)
                    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1851)
                    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Failed to register servlet with name 'dispatcher'.Check if there is another servlet registered under the same name.

Comment: @Nbait Please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.